# I don't know how to describe this well but it's something to do with integer

Tags: java

```
if (Weight <6)
            {
                Price = 5;
                System.out.println("The price of cleaning will be" + Price);
            }
            else if(Weight > 5 < 10)
            {
                Price = 8;
                System.out.println("The price of cleaning will be" + Price);
            }
            else if(Weight >=10)
            {
                Price = 12;
                System.out.println("The price of cleaning will be" + Price);
            }
```

on the else if (weight > 5 < 10). I'm getting a boolean error how do I fix that part?

I expected it to know the difference. Please, I need help on this part, this work I'm doing is due in 3 hours

Answer (score 2):

It is not a Java syntax.
You need to change the `Weight > 5 < 10` to `Weight > 5 && Weight < 10`.

And by the way, we recommend using lowercase letters as initial characters for variables in Java.

Comment: Oh my god I actually forgot about the &&, thank you for the help, I was stuck on that part for a few hours

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the weight should be larger than five and less than ten for the condition in question, try:

```
if (weight > 5 && weight < 10)
```

Answer (score -1):

brother you are are not using "&&" between two statements
so it should be something like

```
else if(weight > 5 && weight < 10)
```

Happy Coding!!!!